# Change the speed of an animation halfway through?

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview

I want my app to play an animation when a press a button however I want the speed of the animation to slow down halfway through? Currently my app plays a sound/animation when I press a button, however the last 50% of the frames are too fast and I want it to slow down.

Here is my code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController {

}
- (IBAction)Button {

    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);

}




-(IBAction)startanimating{
    animatedimage.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_00.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_05.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_10.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_15.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_20.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_25.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_30.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_35.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_40.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_45.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_50.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_50.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_45.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_40.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_35.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_30.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_25.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_20.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_15.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_10.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_05.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_00.png"],nil];




    [animatedimage setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
    animatedimage.animationDuration = 0.7;
    [animatedimage startAnimating];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    NSURL *buttonURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AVTREV" ofType:@"mp3"]];

    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)buttonURL, &SoundID);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Frame 50 is where I want it to play at a much slower speed. Any help would be fantastic thank you!

Comment: `animatedimage` is a `UIImageView`?

Comment: break it down into two animations? one at 100% speed and the other at 50%

Comment: @user1846108 how do I do this exactly what is the best way?

Answer (score 3):

With the current code you have an array with 22 items in it.  To achieve the desired effect, you can use an array with 33 items in it, by duplicating each item after `frame_50`, so that the entries in the array look like this

00 05 10 ... 45 50  50 50 45 45 40 40 ... 05 05 00 00

Since the filenames follow a predictable pattern, you can even use a loop to create the array.

```
int i;
NSString *name;
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray new];
for ( i = 0; i <= 50; i += 5 )
{
    name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"frames_%02d.png", i];
    [tempArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:name]];
}
for ( i = 50; i >= 0; i -= 5 )
{
    name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"frames_%02d.png", i];
    [tempArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:name]];
    [tempArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:name]];    // add the frame twice
}
animatedImage.animationImages = tempArray;
```

edit -- The code above is intended to replace the array initialization code

```
animatedimage.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_00.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_05.png"],
                                     ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I am so lost. Do I delete all my current array frames? where do I put the following code?

Comment: Actually I slightly understand what you mean now. About duplicating frames, thats really smart.

Comment: @rocky90 sorry, didn't get notified for your first message.  I've added to my answer, but it sounds like you've already figured it out :)

Comment: Thanks, also I am having more trouble. I am trying to make an App which is a speedometer and when you click a button it sort of moves the speedometer like a real car. The only issue is what I want is to press the twice in a row instead of reseting the playing the animation again. I want it to move twice as much basically?

Comment: To reiterate what I want is basically "hold button for 0.5 seconds play animation frames 1,2,3,4,5 but hold for 1 second play animation frames 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. And pressing the button 0.5 seconds twice in succession plays 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. also. @user3386109

Comment: To control the animations like that, you need to use CALayers and the lower level animation functions, like CAKeyFrameAnimation.  The UIImageView animations are primarily for repeating fixed animations, e.g. a flappy bird flapping its wings while the UIImageView is moved around the screen to make the bird move.